# Are these tests enough to check if a web app is vulnerable to Padding Oracle? How to test further?

Tags: cryptography, asp.net

**SCENARIO:**

a web application using with ASP.NET. In the home page source code there are links like:

```
./WebResource.axd?d=[string with 87 characters]

./ScriptResource.axd?d=[string with 172 characters]
```

where in the case of WebResource the string presents 3 underscores, like `aaaaa_bbbb_ccc_ddd`, where `a`'s string is long 19 chars, `b`'s string is long 21 chars, `c`'s string is long 25 chars.

**TESTING:**

I run these tools

**Nikto**

> - OSVDB-68127: Server may be vulnerable to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2010/MS10-070
>   (based on numeric calculation), thus allowing a cryptographic padding
>   oracle. This vulnerabilty must be manually validated.

**check_patch.pl**

URL: http://www.mindedsecurity.com/fileshare/check_patch.pl.zip
OUTPUT:

> our Website is Vulnerable, patch immediately!

**dotnetdvaluedecode.py**

URL: https://github.com/alexlauerman/ms10-070CheckPatch/blob/master/dotnetdvaluedecode.py
OUTPUT:

> D value length of 128 is evenly divisible by 8, your application is
> likely vulnerable (try more d values if unsure)

I've seen that the output is based on a module operation `%8==0`, how can I further test If the application is vulnerable?